# I want to select record between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
public function getTotalActiveGroups()
{   
    return
    $this->db->where('group_start >=', date('Y-m-d'))
                     ->where('group_end <=', date('Y-m-d'))
                     ->count_all_results('groups');
}
```

### Problem

In my admin page, I want to show groups which is active. For example, groups starts at 26.10.2015 to 26.11.2015 after finishing the course admin page should't show which is not active. In my table has 2 date columns "start date" and "end date" which shows how long course will be run.

Comment: so if active `end date` is empty ?? is it??

Comment: no, when user inserting new group he shows when group start and ends

Comment: so at the creating group user define start and end data is it ??

Comment: check my answer. posted below

Comment: The code in your question does not bear any resembelance to the requirement you quote. Are you asking to employ someone to code the site for you? For a start your events run across a Month barrier so passing a single month as a parameter is unlikely to be of any use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getTotalActiveGroups()
{   
    return
    $this->db->where('group_start <=', date('Y-m-d'))
                     ->where('group_end >=', date('Y-m-d'))
                     ->count_all_results('groups');
}
```

The answer was enough tricky for beginner!!!!)))

Comment: I'm really surprised that no one bump into that simple fix of compassion directions. And obviously it's the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); //include your timezone
$time = date('Y-m-d h-i-s');

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE end_date => '$time' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

> This will return data which only active till now

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I gave my timezone through server. In that way script shows current day

Comment: this day,'27.10.2015'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you filter the date in the SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE (enddate BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-26')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your group_start field has type DATETIME (not DATE) then you need to use MySQL function DATE:

```
$this->db->where('DATE(group_start) >=', date('Y-m-d'))
                 ->where('DATE(group_end) <=', date('Y-m-d'))
                 ->count_all_results('groups');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
public function getTotalActiveGroups()
    {   
        return
        $this->db->where('DATE(group_start) >=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('DATE(group_end) <=',date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+1 month")))
        ->count_all_results('groups');
    }
```